# How to allow a line drawn on Jpanel to rotate according to a specific point

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egeut.png)
I am programming a paint editor for my final year project. One of its function is that when an user select one or more lines, these lines can be rotated according to a specific point(one of the vertex of these selected lines). Besides, when a line is chosen, it will be marked as red and both vextices will be marked. The red vertex is rotation pivot chosen by user. To implement this, i first caculate the rotation angle and then use trigonometric function to caculate the rotated lines.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class MWE extends JFrame{
    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();  
    public MWE(){  
        setTitle("MyFirstFrame");
        setSize(1160,830);
        setLocation(100,100);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel.requestFocus();
        panel.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MWE myFrame = new MWE();
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList selectedLines = new ArrayList<MyLine2D>();
    private ArrayList selectedPoints = new ArrayList<MyPoint>();
    MyPoint rotationP = new MyPoint(247,309,Color.red);
    int lastX = 0, lastY = 0;
    public MyPanel(){
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.requestFocus();
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        addMouseListener();
        Line2D myLine = new Line2D.Double(247, 309, 344, 197);
        selectedLines.add(new MyLine2D(myLine, Color.red));
        MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint(247,309,Color.red);
        MyPoint p2 = new MyPoint(344,197,Color.black);
        selectedPoints.add(p1);
        selectedPoints.add(p2);
    } 
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        for(int i = 0; i< selectedLines.size(); i++){
            g.setColor(((MyLine2D)selectedLines.get(i)).getColor());
            g.drawLine(((MyLine2D)selectedLines.get(i)).getX1(), ((MyLine2D)selectedLines.get(i)).getY1(), 
                    ((MyLine2D)selectedLines.get(i)).getX2(), ((MyLine2D)selectedLines.get(i)).getY2());
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < selectedPoints.size(); i++){
            g.setColor(((MyPoint)selectedPoints.get(i)).getColor());
            g.drawOval(((MyPoint)selectedPoints.get(i)).getX() - 3, ((MyPoint)selectedPoints.get(i)).getY() - 3, 6, 6);
        }
        
    }
    
    private void addMouseListener(){
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                lastX = e.getX();
                lastY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                 double vecCross = (lastX - rotationP.getX()) * (e.getX() - rotationP.getX()) + (lastY - rotationP.getY()) * (e.getY() - rotationP.getY());
                 int c = (Math.abs((lastX - rotationP.getX()) * (lastX - rotationP.getX())) + Math.abs((lastY - rotationP.getY()) * (lastY - rotationP.getY())))
                    * (Math.abs((e.getX() - rotationP.getX()) * (e.getX() - rotationP.getX())) + Math.abs((e.getY() - rotationP.getY()) * (e.getY() - rotationP.getY())));
                 double sqrt = Math.sqrt(c);
                 double cosValue = vecCross/sqrt;
                 double radian = Math.acos(cosValue);
                 
                if(((e.getY() - lastY)*(lastX - rotationP.getX()) < 0) && !Double.isNaN(radian)){
//                                
                    for(int i = 0; i < selectedLines.size(); i++){
                        ((MyLine2D)selectedLines.get(i)).rotationLine(rotationP, -radian);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < selectedPoints.size(); i++){
                        ((MyPoint)selectedPoints.get(i)).rotationPoint(rotationP, -radian);
                    }
                }
                if(((e.getY() - lastY)*(lastX - rotationP.getX()) > 0) && !Double.isNaN(radian)){
                    for(int i = 0; i < selectedLines.size(); i++){
                        ((MyLine2D)selectedLines.get(i)).rotationLine(rotationP, radian);
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < selectedPoints.size(); i++){
                        ((MyPoint)selectedPoints.get(i)).rotationPoint(rotationP, radian);
                    }
                }
                lastX = e.getX();
                 lastY = e.getY();
                            
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
        
    
}

class MyLine2D {
    private Line2D myLine = new Line2D.Double();
    private Color color = Color.BLACK;
    
    public MyLine2D(Line2D myLine, Color c){
        this.myLine = myLine;
        this.color = c;
    }
    
    public int getX1(){
        return (int)myLine.getX1();
    }
    public int getY1(){
        return (int)myLine.getY1();
    }
    public int getX2(){
        return (int)myLine.getX2();
    }
    public int getY2(){
        return (int)myLine.getY2();
    }
    public Color getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }
    
    public void rotationLine(MyPoint pivot, double radians){
        double x1=0, y1=0, x2=0, y2=0;
            x1 = pivot.getX() + (myLine.getX1() - pivot.getX()) * Math.cos(radians) - (myLine.getY1() - pivot.getY()) * Math.sin(radians);
            y1 = pivot.getY() + (myLine.getY1() - pivot.getY()) * Math.cos(radians) + (myLine.getX1() - pivot.getX()) * Math.sin(radians);
            x2 = pivot.getX() + (myLine.getX2() - pivot.getX()) * Math.cos(radians) - (myLine.getY2() - pivot.getY()) * Math.sin(radians);
            y2 = pivot.getY() + (myLine.getY2() - pivot.getY()) * Math.cos(radians) + (myLine.getX2() - pivot.getX()) * Math.sin(radians);
        Line2D rotatedLine = new Line2D.Double(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        myLine = rotatedLine;
    }
}

class MyPoint {
     private int x;
    private int y;
    private Color color = Color.black;
    
    public MyPoint(int x, int y, Color c){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = c;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return this.x;
    }
//    
//    
    public int getY(){
        return this.y;
    }
    
    public Color getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }
    
    public void rotationPoint(MyPoint pivot, double radians){
        double x1 = pivot.getX() + (x - pivot.getX()) * Math.cos(radians) - (y - pivot.getY()) * Math.sin(radians);
        double y1 = pivot.getY() + (y - pivot.getY()) * Math.cos(radians) + (x - pivot.getX()) * Math.sin(radians);
        x = (int) x1;
        y = (int) y1;
    }
}
```

vecCross is dot product of a vector from rotation pivot to original mouse pointer location and a vector from rotation pivot to present mouse pointer location. c is product of the magnitude of these two vectors. the Arraylist, selectedLines, is the lines selected and remain to be rotated. the ArrayList, selectedPoints, is the vertices of selected lines.

in the if arguement, i think '((e.getY() - lastY)*(lastX - rotationP.getX()) < 0 )' can be represented as my mouse moves anticlockwise. because origin of Jpanel is at top left, anticlockwise movement means to reduce its degree.

My Problem:
However, when i select some lines and enter Rotation mode and move my mouse clockwise, these lines dont rotate smoothly, sometimes quick and sometime slow, and those selected points will dettach from vertices, as shown in image. it is really strange because i use the some function to rotate the selected points and lines. can anyone give me some comments?

Comment: Sounds interesting, but your question is too vague. It's too much effort for me to reproduce your problem. If you provide reduced code demonstrating your problem that only requires copy paste to run, I'll have another look.

Comment: I  delete some construct functions and remake my problem. And i am sure that radian caculated is correct and you can just ignore thoso codes. and i use the theory that cosφ=u·v/|u||v|. besides, rotationLine and rotationPoint functions they are similar but i can hardly type all the deduction here. i hope you can give me advices to let me improve. Sincerely @Reto Höhener

Comment: I will when you provide code that I can copy & paste and run without changes.

Comment: I'm looking for a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example).

Comment: I make a new one and i think it contains minimal codes. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eEHAq0l2L_4xDmQYNksJ_rwlzfte_RRf/view?usp=sharing @Reto Höhener

Comment: *"I make a new one and i think it contains minimal codes."* Post it (not the link, the code itself)  here as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: Thankx. I have editted my code and fope for you further respense sincerely. @Andrew Thompson

Comment: Where are the import statements for this [mre]. Without this, I can't copy it into my ide and run it. I have to look up a bunch of swing stuff and import it.

Comment: Sry i am new here, i forget about that. @NomadMaker

Comment: Before posting a [mre] it's best to test it in a new project.

Comment: I have tested it. It can show the problem and works well even in one single java file.@NomadMaker